# translation in celery tasks

Tags: python, django, translation, celery

I used ugettext in one of my tasks. I had edited the po file. But it didn't work. Does anyone know why? thanks!

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

@task
def testtask():
    .....
    msg = ugettext('test')
    .....
```

Read the celery document, I put the language parameter in the task, and do activate(language) before msg = ugettext('test') ,and it works.

Comment: Provide some more information about what you are trying to do, and read this, especially the section at the bottom: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/i18n/

Comment: It's so strange that I used get_language() in task it always showed 'en-us', but my local language was not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django determines the current language using the [LocaleMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.locale). As a celery task is processed out of any request scope, so it will [fall back](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L268) to LANGUAGE_CODE. As you stated you need to activated the language manually, then the language is [bound to the local thread](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L22) and therefore available for `ugettext`.

Comment: 2016 update: as of Django 1.8, [`get_translation`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/common.py) now returns NONE, so you'll need to pass the language into your tasks [as described here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/django-celery/en/2.4/faq.html#generating-a-template-in-a-task-doesn-t-seem-to-respect-my-i18n-settings)